# Open online help in one session of HH

Tags: windows, chm, html-help

I'm creating an online help in CHM for my application.

To open the help from the application on the appropriate page, I'm starting this kind of command:

```
hh path/to/help_file.chm::/the_page_i_want.htm#the_section
```

The problem is that if the user opens a first help dialog, then a second (from the application) he will end up with two help windows. I'd like the second link to be opened in the first window.

How can I do that (is there another way than the plain call to `hh`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the htmlhelp api directly within your program? (htmlhelp.h, search for htmlhelpA function)